# Android Screen Bounds in a Rect

Tags: android

Is there a way to get a RectF of the Android Device Screen Bounds? I'm trying to scale my Path to a RectF that is the exact screen size. I tried

```
 int width = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
 int height = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
 screenBounds.set(0,0,width,height(;
```

Doesn't actually work. I've tried getDrawingRect() on my View that is match_parent and match_height but it did nothing.

Comment: `Doesn't actually work.` how exactly it does not?